# Running Visual Studio C++ Project on Pop OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, visual-studio, c++

I recently changed my Operating System from Windows 10 to Pop OS. We'll when everything else seems to be fine I'm not able to figure out how I can run my Visual Studio C++ Projects in Pop OS. 
The reason for shifting to Pop OS was because I handle a lot of ML projects and was asked to give it a try. But I don't know what to do with my VS c++ projects.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Use visual studio code if you want an alternative.

Comment: But can I run .sln files in VS Code? @Biswapriyo

Comment: No you can't. For alternative use a docker or VM.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a "Makefile" to compile and link.

Here is explained what is a "Makefile"
https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile

Also, you will need an IDE (ex: VS Code).

Comment: Link only answers are generally not accepted as the link can expire and the answer is then useless. Could you edit your answer to include some of the information from the link?